# Personal site URL in User Profile - SSP?

Tags: 2007, user-profile, my-site, administration

User has deleted his Mysite

E.g., Site Action -> Site settings -> Delete this Site.

however his mysite site-collection URL is still present in the User profile in SSP.

Is that expected ?

Update:
Can you let me know the functionality of "Mysite Cleanup" Timer job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the site does not trigger the update to the profile.  You can simply clear the value out for that field in the user profile.  The next time they click the "My Site" link it will provision the site again.

Comment: Let’s say, User "X" left the company and his manager deleted X's mysite. In this case, what will happen while executing "Mysite Clean up Timer job" ?

Comment: I think its related to the Mysite cleanup, but ultimately it is triggered by the removal of the account from Active Directory.  In the instance above you said the "user" deleted their site, which is a completely different scenario than if the manager or SharePoint itself deletes the site.